# Fiware ngsi-javascript node-fetch error when creating entity

Tags: fiware-orion

I use this module : https://github.com/cenidetiot/ocb-sender

I have one file txt and i read line by line. Each line is a new entity. Sometimes if one of this entity has big information i get this get this error when trying create entity:

This is the code to create entity:

```
createEntity(entity, headers = {}){

        this.addTimeStampEntity(entity);
        let t = this
        const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            headers['Content-Type'] =  'application/json'; 
            const options = { // assign the request options 
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                body: JSON.stringify(entity) 
            };
            fetch(t._URLContext+'/entities', options) 
                .then(function(res) {                  
                    resolve({status : res.status, message:"Entity 
                }) 
                .catch(function(err){
                    reject(new Error(`An error has occurred with the creation of the entity: ${err}`))
                });

        })
        return promise;   // returns the promise         
    }
```

And i get this error:

Error: An error has occurred with the creation of the entity: 
FetchError: request to http://192.168.1.5:1026/v2/entities failed, reason: socket hang up
    at /Users/helderoliveira/MyApps/MicroServices/connector-fiware/node_modules/ocb-sender/lib/OCB.js:209:28

So i try use timeout but doesn´t work.

import AbortController from 'abort-controller';

const controller = new AbortController();
const timeout = setTimeout(
  () => { controller.abort(); },
  150,
);

fetch(url, { signal: controller.signal })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    data => {
      useData(data)
    },
    err => {
      if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
        // request was aborted
      }
    },
  )
  .finally(() => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  });
</pre></code>

can you help me understand this problem ?

Thank you!